# Js : sort and rearrange array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

My array object is like below example.

```
[
 {'email':'test@gmail.com', 'name':'abc'},
 {'email':'test1@gmail.com', 'name':'bbc'},
 {'email':'test2@gmail.com', 'name':'aaa'},
 {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cba'},
 {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cab'},
]
```

So my new array will have key value pare of alphabet **A** as a key and values are all object that's name start from **A** alphabet and so on.one more thing is if alphabet **A** has 2 objects that start from **a** then I also want to sort then in ascending order as I show in final output example below

final output I want is like this.

```
[
  "a" : [{'email':'test@gmail.com', 'name':'aaa'},{'email':'test2@gmail.com', 'name':'abc'}],
  "b" : [{'email':'test1@gmail.com', 'name':'bbc'}],
  "c" : [{'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cab'},{'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cba'}]
]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything ?

Comment: Your expected output format is not valid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `reduce` method to create an object and inside `sort` method to sort values by name.

```js
const data = [{'email':'test@gmail.com', 'name':'Abc'},{'email':'test1@gmail.com', 'name':'bbc'},{'email':'test2@gmail.com', 'name':'aaa'},{'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cba'},{'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cab'},]

const sorted = data.reduce((r, o) => {
  let key = o.name.slice(0, 1).toLowerCase();
  r[key] = (r[key] || []).concat(o);
  r[key].sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name));
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: your code is working but one problem is if I have same alphabet in small and capital latter then it's create new key. how to stop that. so if htere is "A" or "a" I want only one key.

Answer (score 2):

You could sort the array and then group it.

```js
var array = [{ email: 'test@gmail.com', name: 'abc' }, { email: 'test1@gmail.com', name: 'bbc' }, { email: 'test2@gmail.com', name: 'aaa' }, { email: 'test3@gmail.com', name: 'cba' }, { email: 'test3@gmail.com', name: 'cab' }],
    grouped = array
        .sort(({ name: a }, { name: b }) => a.localeCompare(b))
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            var group = o.name[0].toLowerCase();
            (r[group] = r[group] || []).push(o);
            return r;
        }, Object.create(null));
        
console.log(grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var array = [
 {'email':'test@gmail.com', 'name':'abc'},
 {'email':'test1@gmail.com', 'name':'bbc'},
 {'email':'test2@gmail.com', 'name':'aaa'},
 {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cba'},
 {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cab'},
]

function getArray(array=[]){

let newObject = {};
array.forEach(i=>{
  let key = i['name'].slice(0,1)
  if( key && newObject[key] ){
     newObject[key].push(i)
    }else{
    newObject[key] = Array(i)
    }
  }) 
  return newObject

}

console.log(getArray(array))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it using array reduce [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```
const list = [
    {'email':'test@gmail.com', 'name':'abc'},
    {'email':'test1@gmail.com', 'name':'bbc'},
    {'email':'test2@gmail.com', 'name':'aaa'},
    {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cba'},
    {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cab'},
]

const newList = list.reduce((acc, currVal) => {
    const firstLetter = currVal.name.charAt(0);
    if(!acc[firstLetter]){
        acc[firstLetter] = [];
    }
    acc[firstLetter].push(currVal);
    return acc
}, {})

console.log(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough the array, create an object based on it and sort it as is being filled.

```js
const myArr = [
 {'email':'test@gmail.com', 'name':'abc'},
 {'email':'test1@gmail.com', 'name':'bbc'},
 {'email':'test2@gmail.com', 'name':'aaa'},
 {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cba'},
 {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cab'}
];

const finalObj = {};
function compare(a,b) {
  if (a.name < b.name)
    return -1;
  if (a.name > b.name)
    return 1;
  return 0;
}

myArr.forEach(item => {
  const alph = item.name.substr(0, 1);
 
  if (finalObj[alph]) {
    finalObj[alph] = [...finalObj[alph], item].sort(compare);
  } else {
    finalObj[alph] = [item];
  }
});

console.log(finalObj);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use lodash groupBy method to achieve desired result.

```
var collection =[
 {'email':'test@gmail.com', 'name':'abc'},
 {'email':'test1@gmail.com', 'name':'bbc'},
 {'email':'test2@gmail.com', 'name':'aaa'},
 {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cba'},
 {'email':'test3@gmail.com', 'name':'cab'},
]

console.log(_.groupBy(collection, (item) => {
    return item.name[0]
}))
```

Comment: this should be a comment imho, please provide some concrete piece of code if you want to make it an answer. Also, the question tags don't include lodash so it would be best if the proposed solution was made with vanilla